# Adding leftbarbuttons and custom title to navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am adding Custom title and leftbar buttons to navigation bar using following code:-

```
    UIBarButtonItem *button1 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popBack)];
    UIBarButtonItem *button2 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWith:button1, button2, nil];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 30)];     
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14]];                 
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setText:@"Detail Controller"];                                                      
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;  //NSTextAlignmentCenter
    self.navigationItem.titleView=label;
```

Here, left bar buttons are not been placed properly and title alignment not coming properly(left  bar buttons are pushing title to right side of the navigation bar).

Comment: [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320-img.frame.width-img2.frame.width, 30)];

Comment: U just need to resize your bar button image's and everything else be good to go. Also [[NSArray alloc] **initwith:** button1, button2, nil]; don't make such silly mistake.

Comment: @walle84 Thank for your suggestion, i am writing code like this [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, button2, nil] ; and it was typing mistake in question.

Comment: @user3373798 vote up would be appreciated ! Your welcome :)